# Regex match question

Tags: regex, match

If I have a string such as

lotsofcrap"somethingimportant"moreotherstuff

is it possible to get Regex to match just whatever is between the " ", **excluding** the quotation marks?  So the way to detect it would be something like **".*"**, but that will return **"somethingimportant"** rather than just pure **somethingimportant**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"(.*)"
```

You can use parenthese to create a capturing group. How you access it depends on the language/library you're using--typically the capture groups are available as `$1` or `\1` in Perl-like languages. For example, in Perl:

```
'hello "world" !!!' =~ /"(.*)"/;
print "$1\n";
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't solve the problem completely, since the group won't contain the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

If your regex engine supports zero-width assertions (look-behinds and look-aheads),

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?=")
```

will match a sequence of non-quote characters, where there occurs a quote before and a quote after.

However, this is silly.  You should simply

```
"([^"]*)"
```

match everything, including the quotes, and then pull group 1 (the set of parentheses) out of the match.

Answer (score 1):

Try `"(.*?)"`

The `?` means that the  `.*` will expand as needed (until it matches the next )" in this case).

**Java Code:**

```
static String regex = "\"(.*?)\"";
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

public static List<String> getMatches(String inputText) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(m.find()){
        list.add(m.group(1));
    }
    return list;
}
```